# Pytest support for unittest.installHandler

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-django

I'm looking at switching our Django project's tests to use Pytest and pytest-django. The problem I've run into is that I can no longer cleanly halt a test run in the middle.

The default Django test runner has nice [support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests) for this:

> If you press Ctrl-C while the tests are running, the test runner will wait for the currently running test to complete and then exit gracefully. During a graceful exit the test runner will output details of any test failures, report on how many tests were run and how many errors and failures were encountered, and destroy any test databases as usual. Thus pressing Ctrl-C can be very useful if you forget to pass the --failfast option, notice that some tests are unexpectedly failing and want to get details on the failures without waiting for the full test run to complete.
>
> If you do not want to wait for the currently running test to finish, you can press Ctrl-C a second time and the test run will halt immediately, but not gracefully. No details of the tests run before the interruption will be reported, and any test databases created by the run will not be destroyed.

Is there any support for this in Pytest or pytest-django? I've done some digging, and it looks like you'd have to call [`unittest.installHandler()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.installHandler), then somehow tell Pytest to halt the run.

With Pytest, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> just halts the test immediately without any tear down. Calling `installHandler()` means that it doesn't stop the run.

Comment: Maybe you can specify/select tests, `pytest somepath - run all tests below somepath`, or some other [options](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#cmdline) - from the docs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @PetarP, Pytest has lots of options for selecting which tests it will run. However, the feature I like in unittest is that it will let you change your mind *after the run has started*. Especially when you have a test suite that takes several minutes to run, it's nice to be able to stop it cleanly when you notice something wrong, or you want to restart it for some reason.